# How to set usual background when IsEnabled of control is false

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design

I don't want to change user my Calendar, so I set IsEnabled = false. But I don't like its background:
[image: disabled]

I want to see them as usual background:

[image: notdisable]

Is there any possibilities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `Calendar.BlackoutDates` property to disable particular dates or date ranges.

**C#**

```cs
Calendar calendarWithBlackoutDates = new Calendar();

// Add the dates that are not selectable.
calendarWithBlackoutDates.BlackoutDates.Add(
  new CalendarDateRange(new DateTime(2009, 1, 2), new DateTime(2009, 1, 4)));
```

**XAML**

```xml
<Calendar Margin="20" SelectionMode="MultipleRange"  
          IsTodayHighlighted="false" 
          DisplayDate="1/1/2009"
          DisplayDateEnd="1/31/2009"
          xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

  <Calendar.BlackoutDates>
    <CalendarDateRange Start="1/2/2009" End="1/4/2009"/>
  </Calendar.BlackoutDates>
</Calendar>
```

Visit the API reference for the full example: [Calendar.BlackoutDates Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.calendar.blackoutdates?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#examples).
Read this article for further knowledge on how to handle the `Calendar` control: [Calendar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/calendar?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

I recently had similar problems with disabling wpf controls and the resulting style. For me setting IsHitTestVisible = False, was the best option. But not 100% sure if this only disables mouse interactions or also the predefined keyboard controls.